# Create 3 checkboxex in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create initially a checkbox with tkinter package. So I have a big dataframe which I parse and store the info for the checkbox in a array. The checkbox works, but when I press `"Add Metrics:"` it misses some of the attributes I clicked on. Do you know how to resolve this? 
Also, I would like to create another 2 checkboxes like this one(only with other input date) and to display them next to each other. How can I do this?
Also, how can I store the `values` array in memory so I can use those value after I quite Tkinter?

Thank you a lot!

This is my code:

```
def add_metrics(*args):
   values = [(metric, var.get()) for metric, var in data.items() if var.get() == 1]
   print(values)

data = {}

top = Tk()

mb=  Menubutton ( top, text="Metric List:", relief=RAISED )
mb.menu  =  Menu ( mb, tearoff = 0 )
mb["menu"]  =  mb.menu

All_Metric_List = []
for m in dataframe_metrics['name']:
    All_Metric_List.append(m)

for metric in All_Metric_List:
    var = IntVar()
    mb.menu.add_checkbutton(label=metric, variable=var)
    data[metric] = var 

btn = Button(top, text="Add Metrics:", command=add_metrics)
btn.pack()

mb.pack()

top.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hello @BryanOakley! Thank you for your response! My code is based on the response given to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50048561/create-multiple-checkboxes-from-a-list-and-get-all-values  . I'm still a noobie in Tkinter so I don't really understand it fully

Comment: *"it misses some of the attributes I clicked on"*: **Works for me as expected**.

Comment: Sorry about my comment about `add_checkbutton`. I didn’t read the code closely enough.

Comment: @stovfl Managed to get to it work too. Do you know how to create 2 more checkboxes next to it that will work simillarly? Also, how to save that values array so I can use it after I close tkinter?

Comment: @stovfl Thank you!! This is the like for my GitHub Gist : https://gist.github.com/Maker2018/558964a2bd1cd0369533931a9f47ab9e

Comment: @stovfl I saw the comments and applied them! Thank you! Can you look up on my comment from GitHub?

Comment: @stovfl Hello sir!! Unfortunatelly I tried to delete a revision and I deleted my whole gist. I created a new one and updated the code. this is the new Gist: https://gist.github.com/Maker2018/4578ee3d673c5ca7e0830216afeed723. I've added there a comment where I asked for advice in creating 2 more text boxex to add a "Start Date" and "End Date". Thank you for your great mentoring sir!!