# Python printing checkbox values

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to print the values of the checkboxes I select. Can someone help point me in the right direction? I am getting an error on this line - print(my_items[item])

This is the error:

*TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not IntVar*

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

top = tk.Tk()
top.wm_title("Checklist")
my_items = ['pizza','breadsticks','wings','CocaCola','brownie'] 
check_boxes = {item:IntVar() for item in my_items}

def confirm():
    for item in check_boxes.values():
        if item.get() == 1:
            print(my_items[item])

for item in my_items:
    CB = Checkbutton(top, text = item, variable = check_boxes[item], anchor = W,  onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=1, width = 50)
    CB.pack()

B1 = tk.Button(top, text = "confirm", command = confirm)
B1.pack()


top.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the error.

Comment: The problem is that item is not a valid index to access a list. Sorry, bur I don't have a clue about TKinter, but in the meantime, you can take a look to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50048561/create-multiple-checkboxes-from-a-list-and-get-all-values

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: see what you have in `print( item )`. List `my_items` needs number but `item` is not number. You have to rewrite all in different way. Why don't get `keys` from dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you created dictionary like

```
check_boxes  = {'pizza': IntVar(), ...}
```

then you should use `keys` and `values` from dictionary

In `key` you get text `'pizza'` which you need

```
def confirm():
    for key, item in check_boxes.items():
        if item.get() == 1:
            print(key)
```

---

```
import tkinter as tk
# from tkinter import * # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred

# --- functions ---

def confirm():
    for key, item in check_boxes.items():
        if item.get() == 1:
            print(key)

# --- main ---

my_items = ['pizza', 'breadsticks', 'wings', 'CocaCola', 'brownie'] 

root = tk.Tk()

check_boxes = {item:tk.IntVar() for item in my_items}

for item in my_items:
    cb = tk.Checkbutton(root, text=item, variable=check_boxes[item], anchor='w', onvalue=1, offvalue=0, width=50)
    cb.pack()

b1 = tk.Button(root, text="confirm", command=confirm) # PEP8: without spaces around `=`, `lower_case_names` for variables
b1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

**BTW:** You can also use `StringVar()` and `onvalue='pizza'`

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def confirm():
    for string_var in check_boxes:
        text = string_var.get()
        if text:
            print(text)

# --- main ---

my_items = ['pizza', 'breadsticks', 'wings', 'CocaCola', 'brownie'] 

root = tk.Tk()

check_boxes = []

for item in my_items:
    string_var = tk.StringVar()
    check_boxes.append(string_var)

    cb = tk.Checkbutton(root, text=item, variable=string_var, anchor='w', onvalue=item, offvalue='', width=50)
    cb.pack()

b1 = tk.Button(root, text="confirm", command=confirm)
b1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you!