# How do I pull a .mdb checkmark to a checkbox in Tkinter?

Tags: python, ms-access, tkinter, treeview

I have a .mdb that has checkboxes.  How do I translate a check boxed in .mdb to a check boxed in Tkinter .mdb extract either as a print or into a treeview?  Any and all thoughts, help, greatly appreciated.  Sample program below.  Omitted .mdb pathway for security.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from tkinter import ttk
import pyodbc

root = Tk()

root.geometry("1500x1000")


def query():
    conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=\\<pathway goes here>.mdb;')
    c = conn.cursor()    
    
    c.execute("SELECT * from users ORDER BY fullname")
    records = c.fetchall()
    
    print_records = ''
    for record in records:
        print_records += str(record[2]) + '\n'#record[2] is the checkbox in .mdb
        
    query_label = Label(root, text=print_records)
    query_label.grid(row=8, column=0, columnspan=2)
    
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

query_btn = Button(root, text="Show Records", comman=query)
query_btn.grid(row=7, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=10, padx=10, ipadx=137)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59830085/python-printing-checkbox-values

Comment: Thank @June7 .  That is helpful, but I am a little confused.  If I have a database that has a field with a checkbox, and I want to display that in Tkinter as a field with a checkbox, would I need to declare record[2] above as a intvar?  Could you walk me through it a bit more?  Appreciate it.

Comment: I know nothing about tkinter and python.

Comment: Understood.  Thank you for looking.